# Directed Graph - How to count the number of vertices from which each other vertex in graph is reachable?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-theory

In a directed graph how to efficiently count the number of vertices from which each other vertex in graph is reachable?

Comment: You can reverse the edges and find the nodes reachable from every node.

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific?

Comment: If you want to do it "efficiently", you should probably say how your graph is stored. Are you using nodes-and-pointers? Or an adjacency list? Or an adjacency matrix? Or something else?

Comment: Adjacency list / Adjacency matrix whatever is more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no cycle in the graph, there can be only one such vertex and it has an in-degree zero, and there are no other vertices with an in-degree zero. You then have to run a DFS to check if all other vertices are reachable from it. So the answer is either one or zero, depending on the result of DFS.

If there is a cycle, then all the vertices in the cycle have this property or none of them have it.

If you detect a cycle, replace all the vertices in the cycle with one vertex and keep a label for that vertex of how many vertices it represents. Use the same procedure as above. I.e., check in-degrees and run DFS from the new node. The answer will be zero or the label.

Detecting a cycle can be accomplished using a DFS.

There might be several cycles in the graph. In that case you have to eliminate all of them. You can eliminate all of them in one linear pass of DFS, but that's tricky. You could also use Tarjan's algorithm as suggested by btilly in his answer.

Comment: You should probably describe complexity of graph algorithms in terms of number of vertices and number of edges (V and E) instead of n, to avoid ambiguity. For example, DFS to check if a cycle exists is O(V+E).

Comment: My answer was independently found but is morally the same as this one, with the exception that I did the research to identify a linear algorithm for your first step. :-)

Comment: @btilly Yeah, I just haven't had the time to do the research, just typed the answer and shut down my computer ;) I think you could also use a modified DFS to achieve the goal.

Comment: @ciamej I bet you could use a modified DFS to achieve the goal..particularly since that is exactly what Tarjan's algorithm is. :-)  (DFS with some dynamic programming.)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) to detect all loops then construct a graph with each strongly connected component collapsed to a single node.

Now in this new graph, it is sufficient to look for a vertex with no in edges.  If that vertex connects to every other one (verifiable with a breadth first linear search), then everything in the strongly connected component that it came from is in your set, otherwise no vertex is in your set.